# Snowflake - area in sq km from 4 points of lat/lng

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gis, geospatial

I have four points that are bounds of a polygon:

[image]

```
ne_lat: 40.485866
ne_lng: -3.648877
sw_lat: 40.427200
sw_lng: -3.708161
```

I've tried to convert it to `GEOMETRY` and I get a value like this: `0.003477955144000122` here's the expression I used:

```
 ST_MAKEPOLYGON(TO_GEOMETRY('LINESTRING(' ||
                             bounds_ne_lng || ' ' || bounds_ne_lat || ',' ||
                             bounds_ne_lng || ' ' || bounds_sw_lat || ',' ||
                             bounds_sw_lng || ' ' || bounds_sw_lat || ',' ||
                             bounds_sw_lng || ' ' || bounds_ne_lat || ',' ||
                             bounds_ne_lng || ' ' || bounds_ne_lat || ')')) AS box,
  ST_AREA(box)
```

But I was told to change it to `GEOGRAPHY` if I want to have the result in m/km but if I change `TO_GEOMETRY` with `TO_GEOGRAPHY` then the `ST_AREA` just returns 0. What am I missing?

Comment: I may be wrong but your question only seems to have 2 points, not 4. As each point needs both a Lat and Long you'd need 8 values for 4 points. As you only have 2 points you have a sting not a polygon - which is probably why this is not working for you.

Comment: Yes, I create the other two as you can see in the Linestring definition (I use ne_lng + sw_Lat and so on to create the other two corners)

Comment: If I change TO_GEOMETRY to TO_GEOGRAPHY then I get ST_AREA = 32,720,652.2949502

Comment: Geez,, I sweat I tried that before and it gave me 0 but it works. Thanks NickW